# Comparing two tables for each column of each row and result as log variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to compare two tables in each row. the tables are as follows:-

Table a:

```
ID  First_Name       Last_name                         Birthdate
1   Shradha         Deshkmukh                       1981-12-25 00:00:00
2   Shradha              Verma                      1981-05-11 00:00:00
3   Divya                 Dutta                     1982-07-21 00:00:00
4   Matthew               Palmer                         1983-12-28 00:00:00
```

table d:-

```
 id fn  ln  dob
 1  Shradha Tiwari  1981-12-25 00:00:00
 2  Divya   Dutta   1983-07-21 00:00:00
 3  Sulabh  Manesar 1975-09-11 00:00:00
 4  Matthew Palmer  1983-12-28 00:00:00
 5  Samuel  Maxwell 1984-05-22 00:00:00
```

Now my original table is having about 17 columns and this is just a simpler version of it. The tables 'A' and 'D' are generated by a query. Table 'A' will be populated and Table D will be like a temporary table that gets its values from the query, compares all the First Names of each table and if it encounters any change , it needs to update the log table By the first name and also mentions all the columns that are different.

For this I have created a temporary table, viz. '#TMP_COMPARE' which takes all the columns of table 'a'. and then compares those columns against that of table 'd' and it has the columns PLN, PDOB, Pmatch which have values 0 by default and are set to one in case all columns match for that row(Pmatch=1), Last name matches (PLN=1), Dob matches (Pdob=1).

Once this '#TMP_COMPARE' compares the two tables I will then update the log table with the columns that dont match for a first name.

```
USE Testing
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TMP_COMPARE') is not null
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #TMP_COMPARE
END 

CREATE TABLE #TMP_COMPARE(
FN varchar(20),
LN varchar(20),
dob smalldatetime,
PLN int default 0,
Pdob int default 0,
 Pmatch int default 0)

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #TMP_COMPARE
SELECT a.fn, a.ln, a.dob, 
case when a.ln = d.Last_name AND a.dob = d.Birthdate
        THEN 1          
        END AS #TMP_COMPARE.PMATCH,
 CASE WHEN a.dob <> d.Birthdate
        THEN 0  
         WHEN a.dob = d.Birthdate then 1 
        END AS #TMP_COMPARE.Pdob,           

 CASE WHEN a.ln <> d.Last_name 
        THEN 0
          WHEN a.ln = d.Last_name            
    then 1          
 END AS #TMP_COMPARE.PLN

FROM dbo.a2 as a  
 JoIN  d ON a.fn = d.First_Name     
END 

SELECT * FROM #TMP_COMPARE
```

Error I am getting is :-

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near '.'
```

What is wrong in my query, and should I do this any other way please advice.
Now this is something very basic that is wrong in my query but I am a newbie and any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
DCS

Answer (score 0):

@log is a single scalar variable value and can only hold a single value at a given time. So you are unable to reference previous values of that variable, just what is currently there.

That means it's only going to display the last value (match) for every record in your select statement.

You may want to move the select inside the loop and change it to an insert into a logging table of some sort. That way you can just select * from loggingtable after the loop is over to retrieve all the data.

There is likely a way better way to handle this also, but I wanted to give a quick response (no time to refactor right now).

Comment: Thanks for your response Derek. my original table is having 17 columns. And I have edited my question, please if you could take a  look and advice on how this query should be and also how shoudl I update the log table. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two character data field to store a result.

```
Position 1 = LN match state
Position 2 = Birthdate match state

11 = LN Match True ; Birthday Match True
10 = LN Match True ; Birthday Match False
01 = LN Match False; Birthday Match True
00 = LN Match False; Birthday Match True
```

Comment: Hi Cape,Thanks for your answer. I am actually looking for something like this. The table originally has 17 columns and I need to compare for each column and store it in a seperate variable like p1,p2..p17. Setting the default value to 0 and if say column 2 matches for the two tables I can set p2=1 else its 0. I am trying to implement your method (please see post below). Please advice.